# CSS for top right corner of the page

Tags: html, css

How would I have a top right corner div as shown in the image.  I want to do something similar though not exactly the same. I think the text is not an image.

[image]

Also, I have seen some websites that has a page hover effect when a mouse is over the top right section. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Could you link to the relevant site, so that we might work out how they transformed the text (assuming it's not an image)?

Comment: If its not an image, they are using css transformations.

Comment: Why such a huge image?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the text isn't an image, none of the other answers will work. Here is some css that rotates a div 45 degrees and works in IE + FF + Webkit.

```
#yourdiv
{
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
     transform: rotate(45deg);
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11='0.7071067811865476', M12='-0.7071067811865475', M21='0.7071067811865475', M22='0.7071067811865476', sizingMethod='auto expand');
}
```

Comment: It's better to just make it an image rather than use W3C-unapproved styles. He'll have to use an image for the background anyways. Might as well throw the text on it.

Comment: For a top right "flag" like that, an image would be better. I actually used that code in an app that required the text to be dynamic.

Comment: @Jud - Just wanted to confirm - This works on major browsers (IE, FF, Safari, Chrome?)

Comment: I haven't extensively tested, and it may require some modification for your purposes, BUT: IE, FF, Safari, and Chrome are represented in the css above (`-webkit`, `-moz`, and `transform` for wishful thinking). The `filter` uses a proprietary IE transformation that should even work in IE6.

Comment: @Jud - FWIW, this doesn't work with FF. Although it tilts the text by 45 degrees, it places it in the top right corner with half of the text hidden beneath the browser's toolbar

Comment: hmm, it works in FF with the css I had in production. I would try setting a width and height for `#yourdiv` and also centering the text, which should correct that issue. Hopefully this got your started and you can play around with it until it works.

Comment: You can set the point where you want the element to be rotated relative to with the css: `transform-origin: left top;`. (You should probably test which corner is the right one). Also, to get it to work with slightly earlier versions of Opera, you should add `-o-transform: ...`.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure it's a transparent PNG

```
#Element {
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   right:0;
z-index:10;
}
```

(An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.)

Answer (score 5):

```
div.topRight {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
}
```

This will assign a division with class set as 'topRight' to the top right corner. I'm sure you can figure out how to get the image to show up properly from that. Make sure you set the proper width and height on it. As for hovering, what exact effects do you want? You can modify the CSS on hover easily, if that's all you want to do.

```
div.topRight:hover {
    // new css rules
}
```

Comment: @animuson - I don't think the text "Take our survey" is an image. It's text.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/H6rQ6/1/):

Css:

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 280px;
  height: 370px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
}

.ribbon-wrapper-green {
  width: 85px;
  height: 88px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green {
  font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 0;
  left: -5px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #BFDC7A;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  color: #6a6340;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
  content: "";
  border-top:   3px solid #6e8900;   
  border-left:  3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
  left: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
       <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">NEWS</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want fixed positioning.

```
#Element {
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   right:0;
}
```